# Update Command doesn't work on a specific page

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008, sql-update

I have been having issues with the update command on a page I have. I have 4 gridviews and 4 detailsviews and none of them will update with the update command. I can insert and delete but update doesn't work. The update button doesn't cause a post back, it just sits there.

I created a new page and added a detailsview and connected it to the same database and same table, and in that page the update command worked perfectly. I even copied and pasted the command queries to the detailsviews on the other page, but no success.

I'm thinking is an issue with the buttons, but why the default update link button doesn't work?

I am using ASP.NET, C# and SQL Server 2008.

I did notice that the update button on the detailsview that works shows: `javascript:__doPostBack('DetailsView1$ctl02','')` on the status bar.

But the update button for the one that doesn't work shows this: `WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$DetailsView2$ctl02", "", true, "", "", false, true))`

**Here's the code for the detailsview that works**

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" 
DataKeyNames="WorkshopName,WorkshopBeginingDate,WorkshopLocation" 
DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Height="50px" Width="125px">
<Fields>
<asp:BoundField DataField="WorkshopName" HeaderText="WorkshopName" 
ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="WorkshopName" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="WorkshopBeginingDate" 
HeaderText="WorkshopBeginingDate" ReadOnly="True" 
SortExpression="WorkshopBeginingDate" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="WorkshopEndingDate" HeaderText="WorkshopEndingDate" 
SortExpression="WorkshopEndingDate" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="WorkshopLocation" HeaderText="WorkshopLocation" 
ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="WorkshopLocation" />
    <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
    </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
```

**This is the code for one that doesn't work**

```
   <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" 
                                    DataKeyNames="WorkshopName,WorkshopBeginingDate,WorkshopLocation" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource20" Height="50px" Width="125px">
    <Fields>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="WorkshopName" HeaderText="WorkshopName" 
    ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="WorkshopName" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="WorkshopBeginingDate" 
    HeaderText="WorkshopBeginingDate" ReadOnly="True" 
    SortExpression="WorkshopBeginingDate" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="WorkshopEndingDate" HeaderText="WorkshopEndingDate" 
    SortExpression="WorkshopEndingDate" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="WorkshopLocation" HeaderText="WorkshopLocation" 
    ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="WorkshopLocation" />
    <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
    </Fields>
    </asp:DetailsView>

**This is the SQL Data source code for the one that doesn't work, it is also the same on the one that works, except for the Datasource ID.**

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:WildLife_EducationConnectionString %>" 
        DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [tblWorkshop] WHERE [WorkshopName] = @original_WorkshopName AND [WorkshopBeginingDate] = @original_WorkshopBeginingDate AND [WorkshopLocation] = @original_WorkshopLocation AND (([WorkshopEndingDate] = @original_WorkshopEndingDate) OR ([WorkshopEndingDate] IS NULL AND @original_WorkshopEndingDate IS NULL))" 
        InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [tblWorkshop] ([WorkshopName], [WorkshopBeginingDate], [WorkshopEndingDate], [WorkshopLocation]) VALUES (@WorkshopName, @WorkshopBeginingDate, @WorkshopEndingDate, @WorkshopLocation)" 
        OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [WorkshopName], [WorkshopBeginingDate], [WorkshopEndingDate], [WorkshopLocation] FROM [tblWorkshop]" 
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE [tblWorkshop] SET [WorkshopEndingDate] = @WorkshopEndingDate WHERE [WorkshopName] = @original_WorkshopName AND [WorkshopBeginingDate] = @original_WorkshopBeginingDate AND [WorkshopLocation] = @original_WorkshopLocation AND (([WorkshopEndingDate] = @original_WorkshopEndingDate) OR ([WorkshopEndingDate] IS NULL AND @original_WorkshopEndingDate IS NULL))">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_WorkshopName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="original_WorkshopBeginingDate" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_WorkshopLocation" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="original_WorkshopEndingDate" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="WorkshopName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="WorkshopBeginingDate" />
            <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="WorkshopEndingDate" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="WorkshopLocation" Type="String" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="WorkshopEndingDate" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_WorkshopName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="original_WorkshopBeginingDate" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_WorkshopLocation" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="original_WorkshopEndingDate" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: @SonerGönül I added the code for the detailsview, as you can see they are exactly the same thing

Comment: where is your update button in code

Comment: @AmitSingh is defaulted on the detailsview. Where can I get more code for it?

Comment: I did notice that the update button on the detailsview that works shows "javascript:__doPostBack('DetailsView1$ctl02','')" on the status bar, but the update button for the one that doesn't work shows this: "WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$DetailsView2$ctl02", "", true, "", "", false, true))

Comment: do you have ValidationSummary control on a page? If no, try to add and check for any validation messages

Comment: @YuriyRozhovetskiy I don't have any validation on this detailsview. The issue appears to be more likely with the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After weeks of researching I decided to remove all the ajax from my page, and update started working beautifully. Apparently the some code was conflicting with the update command on the page.

I had researched the issue for weeks, readded the datasource many times but no success. My last resource was to remove all of the ajax from the page and magically everything worked.